# esp32-pico-4d not working

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, electronics

My power supply is feeding the esp32-pico with 5v tho it says that there is 0 amps power drain, already there I know something isn't working since the power drain should be around 0.080amps, (it can be all the way up to 0.250amps if wifi on)

when I measure the vdda pin where the power goes into the chip it reads 3.3v which is perfect, but any of the other vdda power pins reads 0v, is the chip turned of cause I'm not powering the EN pin directly from the power supply?

in other words, do the other power pins turn off with the chip?

I have now tried pulling 3v straight from the power supply to the EN pin, and it then goes up to using around 0.160amps, but I still get nothing in the com port
a bit clueless for what is wrong?

other information:

I have a powerbumb turning the 5v into 3.3v

if EN = low: module is turned off if EN = high module is on
(don't leave EN floating)
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-d4_datasheet_en.pdf

(I know the antenna doesn't work)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your schematic and PCB design.

Comment: i have added them now

Comment: You must connect *all* of the VDD pins of *all* types to the appropriate power supplies. These aren't like development boards. They are chips. And you must treat them as such.

Comment: Especially the CPU one - or nothing will ever be able to work.

Comment: so every single vdd pin also those named vdda3p3 needs to be connected to power supply?

Comment: (ofc only the amount of v they need)

Comment: DVVA3P3, VDDA, VDDA3p3_RTC, VDD3P3_CPU, VDD_SDIO - they all need connecting.